# Generate SVG in Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to load a SVG with Javascript. I did it quite often with success, but this time it has a strange return.

Here is my JS

```
var xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var container = document.getElementById('svgContainer');
var svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'svg');
svg.setAttribute('xmlns', xmlns);
svg.setAttribute('version', '1.2');
var defs = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'defs');
var lg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'linearGradient');
lg.setAttribute('id', 'lg');
defs.appendChild(lg);
var stop1 = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'stop');
stop1.setAttribute('offset', '0');
stop1.setAttribute('style', 'stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1');
lg.appendChild(stop1);
var stop2 = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'stop');
stop2.setAttribute('offset', '1');
stop2.setAttribute('style', 'stop-color:#000000;stop-opacity:1');
lg.appendChild(stop2);
var rg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'radialGradient');
rg.setAttribute('cx', '171.20810');
rg.setAttribute('cy', '196.85463');
rg.setAttribute('r', '200.00000');
rg.setAttribute('fx', '171.20810');
rg.setAttribute('fy', '196.85463');
rg.setAttribute('id', 'rg');
rg.setAttribute('xlink:href', '#lg');
rg.setAttribute('gradientUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse');
rg.setAttribute('gradientTransform', 'matrix(1.040418,0.796229,-0.814518,1.064316,153.4218,-150.4353)');
defs.appendChild(rg);
svg.appendChild(defs);
var g = document.createElementNS (xmlns, 'g');
g.setAttribute('transform', 'scale(0.2,0.2)');
svg.appendChild(g);
container.appendChild(svg);
var path = document.createElementNS (xmlns, 'path');
path.setAttribute('d', 'M 450.00000 255.00000 A 200.00000 205.00000 0 1 1  50.000000,255.00000 A 200.00000 205.00000 0 1 1  450.00000 255.00000 z');
path.setAttribute('style', 'opacity:1.0000000;fill:url(#rg);fill-opacity:1.0000000;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:8.0000000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1');
g.appendChild(path);
```

So it generates the perfect HTML DOM elements in the proper order, but it doesn't show anything. When I copy the HTML from the source and paste it, it renders the HTML but not the Javascript, but it's the exact same code.

You can see the source [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jLN6h/).

The weird thing is that when I put the radialGradient in the DOM, it works. You can see it in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jLN6h/3/).

So how should I do this? This problem is on all browsers.

Thank you for your help.

=== EDIT ===
With the help of Robert Longson I managed to fix the issue, check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jLN6h/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set xlink:href using setAttribute, you must use setAttributeNS e.g.

```
var xlinkns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
rg.setAttributeNS(xlinkns, 'xlink:href', '#lg');
```

Changing your jsfiddle in this way makes it work on Firefox. I've not tested other UAs but they should work too.

Comment: Didn't work on Chrome, but I did this instead: rg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", 'xlink:href', '#lg'); and this worked !! Thank you so much !